# Sorting csv list (without using csv module)

Tags: python, loops, sorting, csv, import-from-csv

I have a csv file containing about 10 lines of data in the following format:

```
Attendees
ID, name, location, age
001, John, Harper, 53
002, Lucy, Jones, 23 
etc...
```

I need to import it into python then sort the records by age. I want to do it using some kind of comparison loop (this is what we have been taught in class).

I've imported the records into python as one long list and split it into the seperate records but I'm having trouble with how to convert the age value into an integer (tried int(item[3]) but I got an error message) and also how i can loop through the lists one by one and refer to the last one without them having individual names.

This is what I have so far:

```
text_file = open("attendees.csv", "r")
lines = text_file.readlines()
print(lines)
new_list = []
for line in lines:
    item = line.strip().split(',')
    new_list.append(item)
print (new_list)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: So what is the error message you got?

Comment: TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()

Comment: Sorry I should add I've been playing around with the code a lot and what I posted didn't include the bit that got that error message which was     if item[3] >= 0:
        new_list.append(item)

Comment: You can [edit] your post to include error messages and more details.

Comment: Maybe you tried to convert header -  `int("age")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to skip the first two lines of your input. You can't convert e.g. `age` to and integer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - I stored the first two lines as seperate lists and am now working with the rest of the data - and converting the age value into an integer without the error message.

Comment: Good to hear. It's polite to accept answers if you are satisfied with the solution. This will also indicate to other users across the site that the question has been answered, and you don't need further help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to skip over the title and header rows in your file to stop the sort from breaking. Next read all of the rows into a list. Finally sort the rows based on the integer value held for the `age` column:

```
with open('attendees.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    title = next(f_input)
    header = next(f_input)
    rows = [[col.strip('\n ') for col in row.split(',')] for row in f_input]

for row in sorted(rows, key = lambda x: int(x[3])):
    print row
```

This would display the following output for your sample input:

```
['002', 'Lucy', 'Jones', '23']
['001', 'John', 'Harper', '53']
```

Note, it is safer to use always use Python's `with` keyword when dealing with files. This ensures the file is automatically closed when the script goes outside its scope.